# Can't start Cloudera Manager, site not reachable

Tags: cloudera-manager

I have a small cluster with three nodes on my home server for learning purpose.

It was working fine after it was initially set up.

I haven't used it for a month and today when I try to use it, I found Cloudera Manager GUI cannot be accessed, I checked the network between the 3 nodes are good, they can ping to each other.

On master node where CM is installed, I tried service cloudera-scm-server start, it shows me [OK] in green; when I check the status it shows the following info:

```
[root@pocnnr1n1 ~]# service cloudera-scm-server status -l
● cloudera-scm-server.service - LSB: Cloudera SCM Server
   Loaded: loaded (/etc/rc.d/init.d/cloudera-scm-server; bad; vendor preset: disabled)
   Active: active (exited) since Fri 2017-09-15 20:58:24 EDT; 18min ago
     Docs: man:systemd-sysv-generator(8)
  Process: 107428 ExecStop=/etc/rc.d/init.d/cloudera-scm-server stop (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)
  Process: 107467 ExecStart=/etc/rc.d/init.d/cloudera-scm-server start (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)

Sep 15 20:58:19 pocnnr1n1.raymond.com systemd[1]: Starting LSB: Cloudera SCM Server...
Sep 15 20:58:19 pocnnr1n1.raymond.com su[107494]: (to cloudera-scm) root on none
Sep 15 20:58:24 pocnnr1n1.raymond.com cloudera-scm-server[107467]: Starting cloudera-scm-server: [  OK  ]
Sep 15 20:58:24 pocnnr1n1.raymond.com systemd[1]: Started LSB: Cloudera SCM Server.
```

So, is the Cloudera Manager service started or stopped?

When I try to access CM through GUI, it shows below in chrome:

> This site can’t be reached
>
> 192.168.211.251 refused to connect. Search Google for 192 168 211 251 7180 ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED

Can anyone help me to fix it? Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error when I attempted to start mariadb and failed was because there are dead processes, could be related to previous failed attempt, I killed those failed processes, and restart the mariadb with success, after that, cloudera-scm-server starts successfully.

Thank you. I hope this help for later viewers.

Answer (score 1):

This indicates the Cloudera Manager startup runs into an error. What you should do is to check the log file of your Cloudera Manager, which should be located at `/var/log/cloudera-scm-server` directory. Since this is a POC cluster, I assume that when you set it up, you did not use the external database like MySQL. Instead, you probably used the embedded postgresql database. If that's the case, please make sure the embedded database process is running while you start up the Cloudera Manager Server. To check the status of embedded db, you can do

```
service cloudera-scm-server-db status
```

Comment: Thank you Lan, it is using mysql, and checking the status using your command shows not running:
[root@pocnnr1n1 ~]# service cloudera-scm-server-db status
pg_ctl: no server running
service cloudera-scm-server-db start shows [FAILED]

Comment: It is the same idea ~ you need to make sure your database is running before starting CM

Comment: Thank you, I finally made the mariadb up and running, after that, cloudera-scm server is started and CM is accessible now